# perl equal strings returns 0 even if they are equal

Tags: perl, string, comparison

Perl is continuing to surprise me. I have a code which takes an input from the command line and checks if it is in a file. I have a file like this:

ls

date

pwd

touch

rm

First i read this file as

```
open(MYDATA,"filename") or die "Can not open file\n";
@commandlist = <MYDATA>;
chomp @commandlist;
close MYDATA;
```

the argument is in $commandname variable. To check if it is correct i printed to screen.

```
print $commandname."\n";
```

it works well. then i write the code.

```
$count = @commandlist;
for($i=0;$i < $count;$i++)
{
    print $commandname;
    print $commandlist[$i];
    print "\n";
    if($commandname eq $commandlist[$i])
    {
        print "equal\n";
    }
}
```

and it does not print 'equal'. but it should do becaues $commandname variable has the value 'ls' which is in the file. i also print the value of $commandname and $commandlist[$i] to see if "visibly" they are equal and i get the output:

```
ls
lsls
lsdate
lspwd
lstouch
lsrm
```

here i see that they got the same value but why never eq operator evaluates to zero.
Additionally to get this task done, I have tried various methods all of which come to be useless like making a hash from the array and using exists. 
I am struggling for this seemingly easy problem for a day but i just dont get it. 
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
when i change the above loop as below

```
$count = @commandlist;
for($i=0;$i < $count;$i++)
{
    print $commandlist[$i];
    print $commandname;
    print "\n";
    if($commandname eq $commandlist[$i])
    {
        print "equal\n";
    }
}
```

I got an output like.

```
ls
ls
lste
lsd
lsuch
ls
```

it seems like for some reason it overwrites some characters.

EDIT:

my whole script is like:

```
#reading file code, i posted above
while(<>)
chomp($_);
$commandname = $_;
if($commandname eq "start"){
##something here
} elsif ($commandname eq "machines"){
##something here
} else {

    $count = @commandlist;
    for($i=0;$i < $count;$i++)
    {
        print $commandlist[$i];
        print $commandname;
        print "\n";
        if($commandname eq $commandlist[$i])
        {
            print "equal\n";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you print the variables wrapped in some tags (such as print "--$commandname--\n"; or print "--" . $commandlist[$i] . "--\n"; to see if there isn't any whitespace / crlf which is in the variables?

Comment: i did not try that but i know that there arent any white spaces because the output i get i also posted above.

Comment: "when i change the loop as below" That loop looks identical to the one above. Use `print "cmd: ($commandname)\n"` to see exactly which print belongs to which data, and exactly what characters are in it.

Comment: The reason characters appear to be overwritten is because the lines in your text file are delimited with carriage-return+linefeed, rather than just linefeed. Obviously you're running your script on a Windows machine with a possibly misconfigured version of Perl.  To fix, you'll need to $commandlist[$i]=~s/\r?\n$//; before you compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit change in the code would result in what you are looking for, "chomp" the string from array before you put it for comparison. Here it is

```
chomp $commandlist[$i];

if($commandname eq $commandlist[$i])
{
    print "equal\n";
}
```

EDIT: as per perldoc [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) when you are chomping a list you should parenthesis. So, in your case ... instead simply saying

```
chomp @commandlist
```

make it like

```
chomp(@commandlist)
```

FINAL EDIT: I tried this and worked fine. Give it a try

```
$commandname = $ARGV[0];

open(MYDATA,"chk.txt") or die "Can not open file\n"; 
@commandlist = <MYDATA>; 
chomp(@commandlist);
close MYDATA; 

print $commandname."\n"; 

$count = @commandlist;
print $commandname; 
for($i=0;$i < $count;$i++) 
 {

 print $commandlist[$i]; 
 print "\n"; 
 if($commandname eq $commandlist[$i]) 
 {   
  print "equal\n";   
 } 
 }
```

Comment: @user756790, I tried it in my machine and it did worked. Also, not sure from where you are reading the $commandname scalar (from file or through user input) ... trying chomping $commandname as well before you do the comparison. That might solve.

Comment: @user756, see final edit. issue is with chomping command line input. hope this helps

Comment: thank you. but i still did not manage:) in my full code i have a while loop as while(<>) . i read line and if that line is "start" i do something, if "machines" i do sth .... And i do this using some if elsifs . So probably i am missing something here. I will add an edit to show this.

Answer (score 3):

The overwritting indicates the presence of a CR. The lines end with `CR` `LF`, but you only remove the `LF` with `chomp`. Change

```
while (<>) {
    chomp($_)
```

to

```
while (<>) {
    s/\s+\z//;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider restructuring your code as:

```
my $path='filename';
my $match='ls';
```

#### part 1 - read the file

```
open(my $fh, '<', $path) or die "failed to open $path: $!";
my @commandlist=<$fh>;
chomp @commandlist;  
# or you can combine these lines as: 
#    chomp(my @commandlist=<$fh>);
# because chomp operates on the array itself rather than making a copy.
close($fh);
```

or

```
use File::Slurp qw/ read_file /; 
# see http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Slurp/lib/File/Slurp.pm

my @commandlist=read_file($path);  # result is pre-chomped!
```

#### part 2 - check for a match

```
foreach my $command (@commandlist) {
  print "$match equals $command\n" if $match eq $command;
}
```

One important consideration is that each line in your file must contain *only* the command name and cannot begin or end with any spaces or tabs.  To compensate for possible leading or trailing whitespace, try:

```
foreach my $command (@commandlist) {
  $command=~s/^\s+|\s+$//g; # strip leading or trailing whitespace
  print "$match equals $command\n" if $match eq $command;
}
```

And finally, always start your Perl script with a Perl developer's bestest friends:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

which will catch most (if not all) errors caused by sloppy programming practice. (We all suffer from this!)

Comment: If you don't have File::Slurp on your computer (assuming it's a Linux machine), you can type: 'cpan File::Slurp' at the command prompt to retrieve and load it. For Windows, use the ActiveState Perl Package Manager.

Comment: The three-argument version of open() is preferred because it reduces the possibility of unexpected side-effects for odd file names.

Comment: Finally, the s operator with the regular expression: s/^\s+|\s+$//g will globally match any whitespace at the beginning (^) or end ($) of a line and remove it.

Comment: my input file is well formatted i mean as i expect it to be. once i get the code work i would consider using regexps to make it more reliable. Also do the above file reading methods have different from what i use? because from the output i posted i know it read ok. İs it possible that some other part of the program causing the issue, because i have some while loops and if elsif checks before coming to that part.